# Notation and explanation for certain conditional random variables

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, random-variable

This is a two part question. I apologize if the title and tags are vague. Please edit if a more suitable title or tags are appropriate.

### Part 1

Ok, so if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, continuous random variables with range $\mathbb{R}$, then we can write (assuming pdfs exist):

\begin{align*}
P(Y \gt X) &= \int_{\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \; y \gt x\}} p_{X,Y}(x,y) \; dx dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^y p_X(x)p_Y(y) \; dx dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P_X(X \leq y) \; p_Y(y)  \; dy \\
&= E_Y[P(X \lt Y|Y)]
\end{align*}

Is the last step valid, and how would one read this out loud / explain it intuitively?

### Part 2

<s>Next, take $Y$ to be Bernoulli with range $\{0, 1\}$ and $X$ with the same range as before. However, $X$ and $Y$ are now **not** independent. I want to consider the distributions, $X|Y=0$ and $X|Y=1$, and proceed like the previous case with $X|Y=0$ taking the place of $X$ and $X|Y=1$ taking the place of $Y$, but I'm kind of lost in notation and understanding.</s>

1. How do we write that $X|Y=1$  is independent of $X|Y=0$? What is the notation for the joint distribution?
2. Does it even make sense that $X|Y=1$ and $X|Y=0$ could be independent? In words, it seems like it's feasible: the distribution of the value of $X$ given that $Y=1$ might not tell you anything about the distribution of the value of $X$ given that $Y=0$.
3. $P(X|Y=1 \gt X|Y=0)$ seems horribly confusing. What is the notation for this?

#### Edit: update for Part 2

What I wrote for part was gibberish. So let me update with what my intentions were.

Consider **four** random variables: $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$. The ranges of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both $\mathbb{R}$, while the ranges of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are both $\{0,1\}$. Similar to Part 1, I am interested in computing:

$$
P(X_1 > X_2 | Y_1=1,Y_2=0)
$$

I was curious what assumptions on the $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ allow for a similar calculation. It turns out that we must have both that $(X_1,Y_1)$ is independent of $(X_2,Y_2)$ and $Y_1$ is independent of $Y_2$. Under these assumptions,

$$
P(X_1 > X_2 | Y_1=1,Y_2=0) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} P(X_2 \lt x_1 | Y_2=0) p(x_1|Y_1=1) dx_1
$$

Comment: In Part 2 (2), there must be a typographical error. In Part 2 (3), yes it's horribly confusing--what do you mean?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no random variable defined as $X|Y=1$. So the whole Part 2 does not make sense within probability theory.

Comment: @Xi'an yes, my part 2 was not well thought-out. I've clarified what I intended in the edit above.

Answer (score 2):

Part 1: this is valid, and it would be entirely reasonable to go directly to the last equality, as you are basically rederiving a special case of the law of total expectation.  Recall that for random variables $A$ and $B$ we can write $\text{E}(A) = \text{E}[\text{E}(A \mid B)]$.  Since probabilities can themselves be viewed as expectations your equation follows from this.

Part 2: you're not being very clear about the underlying probability model, so it's difficult to answer this.  In particular, what does it mean to talk about $X \mid (Y = 0)$ and $X \mid (Y = 1)$ being independent?  Are we sampling $X$ under the condition that $Y = 1$, and then taking another realization of $X$ under the event $Y = 0$?  These random variables could be either dependent or independent, regardless of the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.  But, I suspect that this isn't what you mean.

Comment: Basically, I want to apply the result of Part 1 to the random variables $X|Y=0$ and $X|Y=1$ in place of $X$ and $Y$ in Part 1 respectively (overloading variable names, sorry). You are correct in your interpretation: I'm interested in the probability that a realization of the value of $X$ given $Y=1$ is larger than a realization of the value of $X$ given that $Y=0$. To this end, I need to consider (in)dependence of these random quantities, which I think coincides with your last couple of sentences.

Comment: I guess I'm just caught up on notation. Usually, we just say two random vars, $A$ and $B$, are independent if $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$. In this case, $A:=X|Y=1$, $B:=X|Y=0$. Is there a nice or accepted way of writing that these quantities are independent?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what you mean by that last equality, or where the RHS comes from. Let me try to be more clear: $X$ is a continuous rv. $Y$ is Bernoulli. Define the new rv's, $A = X|(Y=1)$ and $B = X|(Y=0)$. This is a valid thing to do, no? From Part 1, $P(A \gt B) = E[ P(A \gt B |A) ]$. I'm simply asking how this can be written without introducing the new variables, $A$ and $B$? Furthermore, I'm asking how to write the intermediate steps without introducing $A$ and $B$, as well.

Comment: Ok, I misread the post and thought $X$ was also Bernoulli.  I'll repost a corrected comment.

Comment: If you want to apply the idea from the first part (which by the way should probably use the notation $E[P(X<Y \mid Y)]$; $P_X(X \leq Y)$ doesn't make a lot of sense) then you would write this expectation as $P(Y=1)P(X<Y \mid Y=1)+P(Y=0)P(X<Y \mid Y=0)$.  We aren't introducing any new r.v.'s here, everything is in terms of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Yes, but that's just $P(Y \gt X)$, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for $P([X|(Y=1)] \gt [X|(Y=0)])$.

Comment: What does this mean?  We're apparently talking about two separate realizations of $X$ under different conditions, but not saying anything about the underlying probability mechanism, and for some reason using the same symbol $X$ in both cases.  It's like asking for $P(Z_1 > Z_2)$ without specifying a joint distribution.

Comment: I see. I think this is why I'm confusing myself. So, then you *would* have to introduce new variables, e.g. $A$ is the distribution of $X$ under condition 1, $B$ is $X$ under $0$, AND specify the joint between $A$ and $B$ in order to proceed with something like Part 1?

Comment: No, you would calculate the expectation as I've already described, using *only* the random variables $X$ and $Y$.  $P(X|(Y = 1) > X|(Y = 0))$ is incoherent and not part of the calculation.

Comment: Take $A$ to be a rv whose distribution is identical to $X|Y=1$. Take $B$ to be a rv whose distribution is identical to $X|Y=0$. Then $P(A \gt B)$ is what I'm interested in. **This** is what I meant to articulate in Part 2.